# Pandas resample creates new dates not in index when converting daily data to monthly data

Tags: python, pandas, finance

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd 

data = yf.download('SPY', start='2017-12-31', end='2019-12-31') 
df = data[['Adj Close']] 

df.resample('2Q',closed='left').mean()
```

The output from resample shows quarter-end dates 30-06-2018, 31-12-2018, 30-06-2019 and 31-12-2019. But some of those dates are not within original data. The average is calculated correctly.

These should be the correct dates 29-06-2018, 31-12-2018, 28-06-2019, 30-12-2019.

How can I use resample but output the correct dates that are in the original data?

```
f = {'Date': 'last', 'Adj Close': 'mean'}
df.reset_index().groupby([[d.year for d in df.index],[d.month==6 for d in 
df.index]],as_index=False).agg(f).sort_values('Date')
```

I used groupby, which outputs the correct dates (i.e. the last date of the quarter that is within the original data) but the average is calculated wrongly. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) `df.resample('2Q', closed='left').mean()` gives

```
             Adj Close
Date                  
2018-06-30  260.626654
2018-12-31  268.594670
2019-06-30  273.702913
2019-12-31  297.780020
```

which is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-06-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-12-31'],
              'Adj Close': [df[(df.index <= '2018-06-29')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >  '2018-06-29') & (df.index <  '2018-12-31')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >= '2018-12-31') & (df.index <= '2019-06-28')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >  '2019-06-28')].mean().values[0]]})

         Date   Adj Close
0  2018-06-30  260.626654
1  2018-12-31  268.594670
2  2019-06-30  273.702913
3  2019-12-31  297.780020
```

where the 31st December 2018 has been assigned to Q1 2019.

b) `df.resample('2Q', kind='period').mean()` gives

```
         Adj Close
Date              
2018Q1  260.626654
2018Q3  268.398217
2019Q1  273.943730
2019Q3  297.780020
```

which is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018Q1', '2018Q3', '2019Q1', '2019Q3'],
              'Adj Close': [df[(df.index <= '2018-06-29')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >  '2018-06-29') & (df.index <= '2018-12-31')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >  '2018-12-31') & (df.index <= '2019-06-28')].mean().values[0],
                            df[(df.index >  '2019-06-28')].mean().values[0]]})

     Date   Adj Close
0  2018Q1  260.626654
1  2018Q3  268.398217
2  2019Q1  273.943730
3  2019Q3  297.780020
```

as well as to

```
f = {'Date': 'last', 'Adj Close': 'mean'}
df.reset_index().groupby([[d.year for d in df.index], [d.quarter <= 2 for d in df.index]], as_index=False).agg(f).sort_values('Date')

        Date   Adj Close
1 2018-06-29  260.626654
0 2018-12-31  268.398217
3 2019-06-28  273.943730
2 2019-12-30  297.780020
```

where the 31st December 2018 has been assigned to Q4 2018.

Comment: Using resample, it is possible to get the actual dates (i.e. 29-06-2018, 31-12-2018, 28-06-2019, 30-12-2019) ?

Comment: I don't think so.